# Multiple replication slot for debezium connector

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I want to create multiple debezium connector with different replication slot. But I am Unable to create multiple replication slot for postgres debezium connector.

I am using docker container for Postgres & kafka. I tried setting up max_replication_slots = 2 in postgressql.conf file & also different slot.name. but still it did not create 2 replication slot for me.

```
{
    "config": {
        "batch.size": "49152",
        "buffer.memory": "100663296",
        "compression.type": "lz4",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.dbname": "Db1",
        "database.hostname": "DBhost",
        "database.password": "dbpwd",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.server.name": "serve_name",
        "database.user": "usename",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "hstore.handling.mode": "json",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "name": "debezium-702771",
        "plugin.name": "wal2json",
        "schema.refresh.mode": "columns_diff_exclude_unchanged_toast",
        "slot.drop_on_stop": "true",
        "slot.name": "debezium1",
        "table.whitelist": "tabel1",
        "time.precision.mode": "adaptive_time_microseconds",
        "transforms": "Reroute",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*).public.(.*)",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "$1.$2",
        "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
    },
    "name": "debezium-702771",
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
}

{
    "config": {
        "batch.size": "49152",
        "buffer.memory": "100663296",
        "compression.type": "lz4",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.dbname": "Db1",
        "database.hostname": "DBhost",
        "database.password": "dbpwd",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.server.name": "serve_name",
        "database.user": "usename",
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "hstore.handling.mode": "json",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "name": "debezium-702772",
        "plugin.name": "wal2json",
        "schema.refresh.mode": "columns_diff_exclude_unchanged_toast",
        "slot.drop_on_stop": "true",
        "slot.name": "debezium2",
        "table.whitelist": "tabel1",
        "time.precision.mode": "adaptive_time_microseconds",
        "transforms": "Reroute",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*).public.(.*)",
        "transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "$1.$2",
        "transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
    },
    "name": "debezium-702772",
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "source"
}
```

It creates multiple connector but not multiple replication slot even after giving different slot name. Do I need to do anything over here.

Comment: I see you specified `debezium` for the `slot.name` for both configurations.  Perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: I try to change that as well. i.e. having different slot name. But still it didn't help

Comment: What version of Debezium are you using?

Comment: debezium/connect:0.9.2.Final

Comment: Could you try with the latest in that release stream, `0.9.5.Final` and see if the problem continues?